# Libgit2sharp how to do a mirror push

Tags: push, mirror, libgit2sharp

I am fairly new to Git/LibGit2Sharp and am trying to create a mirror of a git repository using LibGit2Sharp. Following the directions given here: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/577, I first mirrored the external repository to a local folder by adding a remote to it, and used `repo.Network.fetch(remote, fetchRefSpec)` where `fetchRefSpec` is `refs/\*:refs/*`

Now, I want to push the data to another remote repository. Here I am confused. Because, when doing this through git commands, you set the `remote.remoteName.mirror` config entry to true and then do `git push remoteName`. Specifying any other `refSpec` when mirror is set to true gives an error.

However, when using LibGit2Sharp, even after I set `mirror = true`, I still have to provide a `pushRefSpec` while pushing. Providing empty or wildcard `refSpecs` throws exception. I even tried `refs/tags/\*:refs/tags/*`, but I got the same exception. Looping through all branches in the `pushRefSpec` works, but does not create a mirror.

Has anyone tried this? Is there probably a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.mirror` configuration is an option for the git tool. libgit2(sharp) works at a different level, where you need to specify exactly what you want to push.

At the moment it unfortunately does not support refspecs with a pattern on push, so if you want to push every reference, you'll have to add each of them individually as refspecs for the push.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Carlos. Looping through each ref in the local repository helps.

Comment: Hi Carlos. Can you please provide some sample code for that task? I need to do exactly the same, but don't understand how to change destination url. `Network.Push(remote)` tries to push to an old repo and I see no ways to change it.